# bubble_sort para poder ordenar cada caracter na minha lista

Tags: python-3.x, bubblesort

tenho esse codigo, gostaria de fazer um bubble_sort para poder ordenar cada caracter na minha lista txt

````
with open(arquivo_txt, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as arquivo:
    lista_arquivos = arquivo.read().splitlines()

def bubble_sort(lista_arquivos):
    length = len(lista_arquivos) - 1
    unsorted = True
    while unsorted:
        unsorted = False
        for element in range(0,length):
            if lista_arquivos[element] > lista_arquivos[element + 1]:
                hold = lista_arquivos[element + 1]
                lista_arquivos[element + 1] = lista_arquivos[element]
                lista_arquivos[element] = hold
                unsorted = True
                return lista_arquivos


def ordenar(lista_arquivos):
    inteiros = []
    strings = []
    for elem in lista_arquivos:
        if type(elem) == int:
            inteiros.append(elem)
        elif type(elem) == str:
            strings.append(elem)
            inteiros_ordenados = bubble_sort(inteiros)
            strings_ordenadas = bubble_sort(strings)
            lista_ordenada = inteiros_ordenados + strings_ordenadas
            return lista_ordenada```
````